# MQ AtoB and AtoC communication using a single queue?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I have just started work on a software which uses IBM MQ for some communication.

As I understand that MQ can be used for many to one communication and one to many communication.

Lets say there are 3 Business applications A, B and C. A wants to send a message using MQ to B and another message to C but A is only using one queue Queue1.

Now my question is if we can define (in MQMD or otherwise) that a certain message is only for B NOT for C, hence only B can retrieve it from Queue1 whenever B is available. If not how can we do this if it is at all possible?

One other thing is can we make a separate queue Queue2 only for A-B communication?

Comment: What I am not sure is that if there are the same rules for other technologies e.g. RabbitMQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use separate queues. For example use queue `QA2B` for application A to send messages to application B and `QA2C` for application A to send messages to application C. This way traffic is separated out and you can administratively restrict application B from receiving message meant for C and vice-versa.

It is possible to use just one queue wherein application A while sending messages sets a message property that says something like "Message is for B" or "Message is for C". Application B uses a selector to match the property value "Message for B" while receiving messages. Similarly application C also uses selector "Message for C" and receives messages. But note if either B or C receives messages without any selector, then messages can go to wrong hands.